# How to draw a Polygon in QGIS 3.8 on Mac?

Tags: qgis-3

My apologies, this is quite certainly a duplicate of an old question, but I cannot find the answer. I am struggling with drawing polygons in the new QGIS 3.8.3 on Mac.

In QGIS 2 drawing polygons was as simple as enabling the editing mode, clicking the "Add Polygon" button, drawing the polygon by clicking and then right-clicking (Ctrl + click on the trackpad). After this, a pop-up would come and ask to add Feature Attributes.

In QGIS 3.8 everything works relatively similar until the right-click. Nothing happens. Only Esc works and removes the polygon (as it should). Which button am I supposed to press?

[image: ?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! In the settings of my mac, I selected "bottom right click" in my trackpad to act as a secondary click aka right click. So when I click the bottom right of my trackpad, its essentially a right click which allows me to complete the polygon!

Comment: Thank you Rayna. That, indeed, works for me too. For those who wonder what is meant by "bottom right-click", see here: https://macpaw.com/how-to/right-click-on-mac. Seems like this is a bug which will (hopefully) be fixed in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a bug:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31279

I would comment on that saying you are experiencing the same issue and use 2.18 in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have fields in the layer you are editing,

**1) Select *Settings > Options***

**2) Click on the *Digitizing* tab**

**3) Deselect *Suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation***

[image]

*Note: if there are no fields in the layer, the form will not open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not help, as the option is already deselected.